# Microsoft Word's Advanced Layout dialog -- explanation for super users?

Tags: macos, layout, microsoft-word-2011, publishing

Where can I find a detailed explanation of the options in Microsoft Word's Advanced Layout dialog?

[image: Word Advanced Layout]

I am not unfamiliar with desktop publishing concepts and challenges. I understand there are complex decisions to make about positioning, and that Word can't read my mind and know exactly what I want. However, even being willing to sit and learn, I can't figure out what the options in this dialog mean. For example, what does it mean to have Vertical Alignment to the Top of Line? A visual explanation would be ideal.

I have searched [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/results.aspx?qu=word%20advanced%20layout&avg=zwd) and have not found any explanations. The only content I can find just names the items in the dialog, without describing them. I've found little help on the general web; most content ([example 1](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/drwgrphcs/DrawLayer.htm), [example 2](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/Pub0009/LPMArticle.asp?ID=482)) refers to old versions of Word.

I am on Word 2011 for Mac. Thanks.